# Python function which takes a list as input and returns list with indices of sorted elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

I'm trying to make a python function in which I give a certain list, and it returns a list with sorted positions of elements (not starting with 0) .
For example:

```
list = [9,3,4,1]
function(list) = [4,2,3,1]
```

or

```
list = [2,2,6,5]
function(list) = [1,1,3,2]
```

Comment: You probably mean the position in a *sorted* list?

Comment: Make a copy of the list, remove duplicates from it, and sort it. Then loop through the original list and get the index of each element in the sorted copy.

Comment: I understand it can sometimes be hard to google when you don't already know the right technical term to search for, so here it is:  **argsort**.

Comment: @PatrickArtner: Note that this introduces the complication of the values in the original `list` not being unique, and wants the duplicates to share a common index. The duplicate's input `list` was unique, so this didn't come up.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes exact the position in a sorted list

Comment: Why do you want the output for `[2,2,6,5]` to be `[1,1,3,2]`. It should be `[1,1,4,3]` right? Because there are two 2's so they both get assigned rank 1. But they tied for first place, so the next value is in 3rd place, NOT second place. I mean, you can define the problem any way you want to, but it seems very odd to me, personally. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Create a dict with key being elements of the list and value being the position. In order to get the unique value convert the list to set first

```
list1 = [2,2,6,5]
d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(list1)), start=1)}
[d[k] for k in list1]
```

**Output**

```
[1, 1, 3, 2]
```

Comment: The OP provided two inputs; the second of them isn't unique, and this won't work for it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Actually, uniqueness isn't a problem here.  off-by-one-error is (the range is both augmented and offset).

Comment: @ShadowRanger was still editing the post. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: @mad_: You can simplify a bit by making `d = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(sorted(set(list1)), 1)}`; no need for `zip`, storing a separate `set`, `range`, `len`, etc. calls. `enumerate`+dict comprehension is both faster and cleaner.

Comment: Sorting a set is a valid operation? Actually curios now, as I thought it's not something you should do

Comment: @user8408080 sets themselves can't be sorted in any meaningful way, but `sorted(some_set)` produces a sorted list with all the members of that set.

Comment: @user8408080: Expanding on @AdamSmith, `sorted` works on *any* input iterable (generators, strings, etc.), producing a brand new `list` already in sorted order. `sorted`, if implemented in Python, would be exactly equivalent to `def sorted(it, *, key=None, reverse=False): newlist = list(it); newlist.sort(key=key, reverse=reverse); return newlist`; the "takes input, makes new sorted `list` output" design makes it suitable for one-lining many things, e.g. in this case producing a sorted `list` of unique values in `list1` by adding on a conversion to `set` to uniquify before sorting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I think it is all clear now